Sampling from a PDF equal to a product of two known PDFs f(x) and g(x)
Suppose we have two known PDFs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (also we can simply sample from both distributions).
How do you sample $k \cdot f \cdot g\,(x)$ if the corresponding PDF/CDF can't be easily identified ($k$ is a normalization factor)? In particular, I am searching to sample a PDF which is a product of $\mathsf{LogNorm}(\mu_a,\sigma_a)$ and $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_b,\sigma_b)$.
My intention is to apply "weight" to probabilities of the original $\mathsf{LogNorm}$ using a given $\mathsf{Norm}$.
I have found Metropolis–Hastings algorithm, but I am wondering if there is something simpler for the particular case of the product of $\mathsf{LogNorm}$ and $\mathsf{Norm}$ distributions?
Some examples to clarify my question:

Here, person asks about "Hybrid" distribution. From the presented histogram I can say that it is probably what I am searching for. Unfortunately, OP does not speak about how the sampling was performed.
Here, someone speaks about efficiency of the "Metropolis–Hastings algorithm" for the case that seems to be the same as mine.


Ok, I change the description, I wanted something different =)

@Firebug I think you mean $A$ and $B$ are independent.  But if they're not, then there's insufficient information to sample $C.$

Here, I've changed the question.

In the joint distribution from which you want to sample, the log-normal and the normal margins are independent of each other, correct?

Generally speaking, these are two independent distributions. In my practical example, $\mu_b$ is drawn from the log-normal, but I guess it should not change anything.

A very simple but possible extremely inefficient method is to sample $x$ from $g(x)$ and then accept the sample $x$ with probability proportional to $f(x)/f(\hat x)$ where $\hat x$ is the mode of $f(x)$.

@whuber Ah yes, sorry, I had in mind $f(A,B)=f(A)f(B)$ and then went back on it to simplify language, that's the why for the non-sensical statement about marginals I made

Before answering your question I'll note that if a random variable $X$ is defined in this manner as having a pdf given by the product of a log-normal and normal pdf, $X$ is necessarily positive. So I'll assume that $f$ is a log-normal pdf, and $g$ is a half-normal pdf (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). A simple way to accomplish this exactly (i.e. without resorting to MCMC), is to use rejection sampling (see e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684170), where you use either $f$ or $g$ as your proposal distribution. For example, let's say you use $f$ as your proposal. Let $M=\max_{x}g(x)$. The following procedure draws a sample from the target distribution:

Sample $x$ from $f$, and $u\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$
If $u < g(x)/M$, $x$ is a sample from the target. Otherwise go back to step 1.

You can instead use $g$ as the proposal, in which case the ratio you compare $u$ against is instead $f(x)/[\max_{x}f(x)]$. It may be more efficient (in the sense of the acceptance rate of the sampler) to consider $f$ or $g$ as your proposal.

If your target density is a product of positive functions
$$f(x)\propto\prod_{i=1}^k f_i(x)$$
a generic simulation is to use slice sampling, since
$$f(x)\propto \prod_{i=1}^k \int_0^{f_i(x)}\text d\omega_i$$
appears as the marginal (in $x$) of the uniform distribution
$$\tilde f(x,\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k)\propto \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{I}_{(0,f_i(x))}(\omega_i)$$
which can be simulated by Gibbs sampling:

Simulate $\omega_1\sim\mathcal U(0,f_1(x))$
....


k. Simulate $\omega_k\sim\mathcal U(0,f_k(x))$
k+1. Simulate $x\sim \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{I}_{f_i(x))\ge\omega_i}$
This still requires the constraint
$$f_i(x)\ge \omega_i \qquad \forall i$$
to be invertible towards simulating a uniform $X$ over that region.
For instance, when
$$f(x) \propto \frac1x\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{\ln x- \mu_a}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_a}\right)^2\right\}\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{ x- \mu_b}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_b}\right)^2\right\}$$
one can set
\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=\frac1x\\
f_2(x)&=\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{\ln x- \mu_a}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_a}\right)^2\right\}\\
f_3(x)&=\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{ x- \mu_b}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_b}\right)^2\right\}
\end{align}
and invert
$$f_i(x)\ge \omega_i \qquad i=1,2,3$$
into
\begin{cases}
x\le\frac1{\omega_1}\\
\left|\ln x- \mu_a\right|\le \sigma_a\sqrt{-2\ln \omega_2}\\
\left| x- \mu_b\right| \le \sigma_b\sqrt{-2\ln \omega_3}
\end{cases}
which is the intersection of three intervals.

It is not clear what you are asking.
1) There exist independent Log-Normal rv $X$ and rv $Y$ Normal and you want to sample from the distribution of $Z = XY$. Then Firebug comment is your answer. Sample from $X$, sample from $Y$ and compute per observation $Z = XY$.
2) You imagine that there exists a distribution, denote it by $D$, such that its density function $f_D(d)$ is equal to the product of the densities of a Log-Normal distribution and of a Normal distribution. Namely you want
$$f_D = k\cdot f_{LN}\cdot f_N$$
or
$$f_D(d) = k\cdot \frac{1}{d\cdot \sigma_a\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{\ln d- \mu_a}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_a}\right)^2\right\}\cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_b\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{ d- \mu_b}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_b}\right)^2\right\}$$
This is totally different than 1). The random variable that follows a distribution with such a density (if it is a proper density) will have no relation whatsoever to the $Z= XY$ of 1).
3) You sample from a Log-Normal distribution (denote the related rv $X$), you sample from a Normal distribution (denote the related rv $Y$), and then you consider the random variable $W$ defined as
$$W = k\cdot f_{LN}(X) \cdot f_N(Y).$$
This expression has nothing to do with the pdf of $W$, it is the expression that defines $W$ itself, not the distribution that it follows. Again, this is totally different than the previous two. It may use the functional forms of the densities, but here they are just functional forms.
Is what you are asking any one of the three, or something different altogether?

Hi. I think it is the option (2). I added links to some examples of similar questions.

The first link you provide clearly implements my scenario 1), not 2). The second link suffers from the same confusing language and notation as your post. So I guess you need to clarify this first for your self, and then for the rest of us, in order to be able to help you.
